# Tree view in React

Tags: reactjs, treeview

This is my data:

```
{
  "studentId": "P1",
  "assignments": [
    {
      "CourseId": 111,
      "subjectId": "",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t1",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CourseId": 112,
      "subjectId": "s1",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t1",
          "isAssigned": false
        },
        {
          "topicId": "t2",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CourseId": 111,
      "subjectId": "",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t3",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CourseId": 113,
      "subjectId": "s2",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t4",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CourseId": 114,
      "subjectId": "",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t5",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CourseId": 115,
      "subjectId": "s4",
      "topics": [
        {
          "topicId": "t6",
          "isAssigned": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "updatedOn": null,
  "updatedBy": null
}
```

I'm trying to create a tree view in React out of this. I'm using "react-checkbox-tree". The tree view would be created on the assignments object only as the rest of the data is needed only for save functionality.

I have created the basic architecture since I need this in a modal window. It's working fine with hard coded data but I'm finding it difficult to convert my dataset in the format needed for the tree view. Below is the hard-coded object which is working fine.

```
const nodes = [{
    value: 'mars',
    label: 'Mars',
    children: [
        { value: 'phobos', label: 'Phobos' },
        { value: 'deimos', label: 'Deimos' },
    ],
}];
```

Comment: Do u want your final output to look like this? `const nodes = [{
    value: '111',
    label: 'CourseId',
    children: [
        { value: 't1', label: 't1' }
    ],
},{
    value: '111',
    label: 'CourseId',
    children: [
        { value: 't1', label: 't1' },
        { value: 't2', label: 't2' },
    ],
}];`

Comment: Hey @NeelDsouza ! Yes that's correct

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. This is basically converting all first values into object with `{value.., label..}` If there is any specific condition in your code that it should not consider first object always then do mention it in your question.

```js
    const assignments = [
      {
        "CourseId": 111,
        "subjectId": "",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t1",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CourseId": 112,
        "subjectId": "s1",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t1",
            "isAssigned": false
          },
          {
            "topicId": "t2",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CourseId": 111,
        "subjectId": "",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t3",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CourseId": 113,
        "subjectId": "s2",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t4",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CourseId": 114,
        "subjectId": "",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t5",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "CourseId": 115,
        "subjectId": "s4",
        "topics": [
          {
            "topicId": "t6",
            "isAssigned": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
const mapAssignment = (object, key) => ({value: key, label: object[key]});

console.log(assignments.map(ass => {
  let assObj = {...mapAssignment(ass, 'CourseId')};
  if(ass.subjectId) {
    assObj['children'] = mapAssignment(ass, 'subjectId');
    if(ass.topics.length > 0) assObj['children']['children'] = ass.topics.map(child => mapAssignment(child, 'topicId'))
  }
  else if(ass.topics.length > 0) assObj['children'] = ass.topics.map(child => mapAssignment(child, 'topicId'))
  return assObj;
}));
```

Comment: Hi @Neel Dsouza ! its working but it doesn't show the subject. in my object the hierarchy should be course -> subject -> topics , if the subject is "" then topics should be directly under course. You almost did what i need i appreciate it, but can you assist me with this as well?

Comment: I didnt understood. Can u plz add the resulting nodes value for subject = "" like how you want.

Comment: Sorry, so if you look into the object you would see CourseId then SubjectId then Topics which is an array. So i would want it to show CourseId as parent then SubjectId as first child and then Topics as the grandchild. if the subjectId is blank or "" then topics should come directly under Course

Comment: Updated my answer.